# PhP function to validate Xpath or CSS - Behat

Tags: php, regex, behat

I have the function `findElements` on Behat that has a validation to check if what I have passed as a parameter is a Xpath or a CSS Selector. This is the validation part:

```
// If it starts with //, it's a xpath
if (preg_match("/^\/\/.*|^\(.*\)\[(\d+|last\(\))\]$/", $selector) === 1) {
            $type = 'xpath';
        } else {
            $type = 'css';
        }
```

**The thing is:** sometimes, I need to use Xpath like this one:

```
(//div[@class='views-element-container form-group'])[1]/div/div/h3
```

It does not starts with `//`, so the validation thinks this is a CSS selector, and not a Xpath.

**What I need:** Include in the validation that the Xpath can also starts with `(//`.

Thanks!

Comment: Just add a possible `(` to the beginning of your regex like this: `preg_match("/^\(?\/\/.*|^\(.*\)\[(\d+|last\(\))\]$/", $selector)`

Comment: Thank you, it worked! please reply the post so I can mark your reply as the solution :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a possible `(` to the beginning of your regex  by adding `\(?` after the caret like this:

```
preg_match("/^\(?\/\/.*|^\(.*\)\[(\d+|last\(\))\]$/", $selector)
```